# What controls should I use on a Silverlight website for loading textual content?

Tags: silverlight, web, silverlight-4.0

I am embarking on development of a Silverlight based website. I am the lone developer and am doing it on my own (ie, not for any company).

Now I want to load a lot of textual content on the website along with animations and rich user interfaces that can be created using Silverlight. The text content may change from time to time and when that happens, I don't want to do a lot of rework. So I m thinking to load the text from a Word/text file into controls and whenever new content arrives/existing content is modified, I just have to append it to the Word/text file.

This way the application itself remains untouched, only the file contents keep changing. Silverlight doesn't support FlowDocument. RichTextBox doesnt have a Load or LoadFile property. So how do I go about this? Should I make use of Frame, Downloader and similar other controls as well? What do you suggest? What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` does have a `Xaml` property so you could download Xaml files containing the restricted set of textual elements that `RichTextBox` supports.  You could also create a Silverlight editor around which you could create and upload this Xaml text content.

However have you considered whether Silverlight is the right platform to deliver primarily textual content?  HTML is pretty good at that and with frameworks such as JQuery you can create quite interactive experiences that work well across browsers.

Comment: One benefit of using Silverlight, on a mostly-text website is, protection of copyrighted content. You can't cut & paste from Silverlight TextBlocks (you can from a RichTextBox, but you can put an almost-transparent rectangle over it if protection is required).

Comment: Ye, I know I can do it with HTML but I want to try and achieve this using Silverlight. Xaml property sounds good, but won't it require lot of formatting?

Comment: @mamtadalal: The amount of formatting is entirely down to how much much formatting you really want.  It could be just series of `<paragraph>` elements if thats all you want.  Of course if you want no formatting then just use a `TextBox`.

Comment: Anthony and HiTechMagic, thanks for your replies. Anthony, you wrote "You could also create a Silverlight editor around which you could create and upload this Xaml text content." Can you list some Silverlight editors?